# php inject an object and then make it public?

Tags: php, object, dependency-injection, public

Suppose I "inject" a php object into another object as follows:

```
class Customer {
  ...
  function setCustomerLocation(Location $location) {
    $this->location = $location;
  }
  ...
}
```

How can I now make the "injected" location object **public** within the customer, such that from the outside I can use its own public properties and methods as follows (or similarly):

```
$myCustomer->location->getCoordinates();
```

Comment: Why *isn't* it public now? The injection has no bearing on the backing member in this example.

Comment: If you already have location declared as private, you could also use the `__get` magic method to return the local instance of location.

Comment: But if you wanted it to be public, why declare it private in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar I was just making a comment. Maybe he is extending another class that already has location defined as private. Using the magic methods is an easy to access the private properties transparently.

Answer (score 4):

When you add a property dynamically that hasn't been defined like that `$this->location = $location;` **it is public by default**.

To do it explicitly:

```
class Customer {
  public $location;

  function setCustomerLocation(Location $location) {
    $this->location = $location;
  }
}
```